# How to properly restart nodemon server

Tags: node.js, nodemon

When I run a nodejs server with the following command:

```
"start": "nodemon --max-old-space=8192 ./src/app.js --exec babel-node"
```

and I change anything in the code, nodemon automatically reloads the code and restarts the server with the following message.

```
[nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `babel-node --max-old-space=8192 ./src/app.js`
```

**How do I restart the server manually the same way?**

Or in other words: What do I write in the package.json scripts "restart" command to simulate the same behaviour that is done by nodemon automatically?

Thanks

Comment: Typing 'rs' in the console?

Comment: I was searching how to execute a command/callback after Nodemon start/restart and you helped me a lot :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The purpose of `nodemon` is to listen changes of the file and restart the server. If you want manually to restart the server then you no need to use nodemon, you can use just `node` command.

The below code would serve the purpose.

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./src/app.js",
        "restart": "kill -9 $(ps aux | grep '\snode\s' | awk '{print $2}') && node ./src/app.js "
    },
}
```

Answer (score 13):

As stated in the [documentation](https://github.com/remy/nodemon#manual-restarting), you can restart manually by typeing `rs` in the console where `nodemon` is running.
There is no external command to trigger a restart from a different process.
One workaround would be to trigger a restart by simulating a change of a file.
A simple `touch` on a watched file is enough. So you could write a npm script that touches one of the watched files.

```
"restart": "touch app.js"
```

Answer (score 2):

**Say goodbye to** `nodemon`.

### Node v18.11.0

Running in **'watch'** mode using node `--watch` restarts the process when an imported file is changed.

try as follow:

```
node --watch app.js
```

**[For more information](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v18.11.0/)**

Answer (score 1):

Tried a few things to restart `nodemon` from within a running script.

```
var fs = require('fs');
fs.utimesSync(__filename, Date.now(), Date.now());
```

This will touch the current file, which should trigger a restart if nodemon is watching.

Comment: I love this fix, simple and easy to use :)

Answer (score -1):

If you are specifically looking to resolve *"listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use"* error after a while, you can check what application is using the port that nodemon wants to use:

```
sudo lsof -i :4500
```

The above will give you the PID of the app that is using that port. Then you may kill the process by:

```
kill -9 <PID>
```

Answer (score -1):

Source: https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon

> **Manual restarting**
>
> ---
>
> Whilst nodemon is running, if you need to manually restart your
> application, instead of stopping and restart nodemon, you can type **rs**
> with a carriage return, and nodemon will restart your process.